# Align an item in center and other in right with Flexbox

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

I want to align an item in center and other in right using flexbox like the example bellow.

```
+-------------------------+
|         |    |    |    ||
|         +----+    +----+|
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

Here is my code on plunker (Updated with solution):

http://plnkr.co/edit/kYYIOIFQaEMHgvZCKMkf?p=preview

Comment: Look like you forgot to add the image.  Also, please include some code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Err...Image seems to be missing!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have points to submit an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't really do that with `flexbox` using the basic alignment options (at least as far as I can tell).

What you *can* do is add a pseduo-element to fake an extra box to do the work for you. Of course, the box has to have the same dimensions as the item you want to shift over, then you can use `space-between`.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}


.wrap:after { /* centered line for demo purposes only */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-right:1px solid green;
}

.box {
  flex:0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.wrap:before, .box:last-child {
  content: '';
  flex:0 0 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box wide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude! I updated my example on plunker.